# jquery: replace inner child elements with it's text so that the outer element's text returns text only?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Consider an element containing text. `<h1>Title text <span>inner text</span></h1>` or `<h1>Title text <span>inner <b>text</b></span></h1>`

When it's rendered it looks as `Title text inner text`, but in reality, when I want to get the text content of `h1` it returns the inner child elements as well.

How do I make sure that all cases like this are formatted to the following?

`<h1>Title text inner text</h1>`

Basically removing any decorative inner elements? I need to select an element by it's text value and unfortunately these inner child elements interfere. For example when I try to match an element by xpath like `*[text()='Title text inner text']`, it cannot find it because there are inner child elements. To the human reader, it seems natural as the text is seemingly confined in it's own but the underlying html structure says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VwTHF/173/

```
var temp='<h1>Title text <span>inner <b>text</b></span></h1>';

var $temp = $(temp).find('span, b ,h1').contents().unwrap().end().end();
```

Although Barmar's solution look very viable as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will set all the `h1` elements' text to just the text without extra HTML:

```
$('h1').text(function(i, orig) { return orig; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `innerText` property. It returns all the text.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljhvexii.php

usage:

```
var elem = document.getElementById ("myDiv");
message += "\ninner text : " + elem.innerText;

alert (message);
```

see this fiddle here :

http://jsfiddle.net/wxnY4/